# What is "Other dev" in result of command "adb shell dumpsys meminfo" in Android?

Tags: android

I have a big problem about memory leak. I do command "adb shell dumpsys meminfo" and result show that
"Other dev" consumed a lot of memory.
I google about "Other dev" but no information about this. Anybody can tell me What is "Other dev" in android.

Many thanks!

Comment: Assuming you wants to debug memory leak of "your" App (and not the memory leaks happening in your device, caused by other app), you should type : adb shell dumpsys meminfo <your-app's-package_name>. Now, you should observe how your app's memory is divided between different types of RAM allocation. For more info Refer:https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: Thanks ADDTTechnical for quick reply. I added "my-package" to command. Can tell me about "Other dev" row in result of command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the Response from Android Framework Engineer (Dianne Hackborne) about the different columns including "Other" that you are looking for.

[Detailed explanation for profile from "adb shell dumpsys meminfo my-app-name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245489/detailed-explanation-for-profile-from-adb-shell-dumpsys-meminfo-my-app-name)

In a Nutshell,the "Other" Section's allocations can be broadly for any of the following:

1. the memory backing cursors,
2. shared memory areas from ashmem,
3. devices allocating things for you such as graphics textures.